# Highlighting items in TreeView C++ BUILDER

Tags: c++, treeview, c++builder

How can i change text color of some specifec item in TreeView?

TreeView is filled in program.

I mean i want to highlight some Treeview item by changing it text color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to owner-draw the TreeView.  It has [`OnCustomDrawItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.OnCustomDrawItem) and [`OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem) events for that purpose.  On a per-item basis, you can set the  TreeView's `Canvas->Font->Color` property to whatever you want. Since you have access to the `Canvas`, you can draw whatever you want, not just customize the text.